# executionTimeMillisEstimate meaning in explain() executionStats for aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-explain

I have done the following `explain()` with `executionStats` verbosity for an aggregation pipeline in my MongoDB instance:

```
> db.users.explain("executionStats").aggregate([ ... ])
{
    "explainVersion" : "1",
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : { ... },
             ...
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        {
            "$lookup" : { ... },
            ...
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(308)
        },
        {
            "$lookup" : { ... },            
            ...
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(1297)
        },
        {
            "$project" : { ... },
            ...
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(1320)
        },
        {
            "$project" : { ...},
            ...
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(1323)
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

The aggregation detail itself is not important in the context of this question, so I have simplified it. The only thing to take into account is that is that the pipeline is composed of the following stages:

- match
- (first) lookup
- (second) lookup
- (first) project
- (second) project

I understand that `executionTimeMillisEstimate` doesn't mean the time it takes that particular stage but the time measured from the moment in which the operation started. Thus, the actual estimate time for each stage is:

- match: **0ms** (I have an index for the query, so makes sense it is very fast)
- (first) lookup: 308 - 0 = **308ms**
- (second) lookup: 1297 - 308 = **989ms**
- (first) project: 1320 - 1297 = **23ms**
- (second) project: 1323 - 1320 = **3ms**

Is my understanding on how `executionTimeMillisEstimate` correct, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! At that page `executionTimeMillisEstimate` is defined as  "The estimated amount of time in milliseconds for query execution". However, it is not clear what "query execution" means in this context. Does it means the individual stage? Or the accumulated query from the beginning of the pipeline to that particular stage? It seems the second case, but not fully sure... (so I posted this question :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but also think that the second, however you can make few attempts (not necessary with this particular query) to prove or disprove it

Comment: I too have the same doubt and I am thinking it is the second one(accumulated). Another observation I made is, the $cursor.executionStats.executionTimeMillis is nearly equal to the accumulated time.